# Laravel Datatable doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

I'm using [Datatables Package for Laravel](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/wiki) on Laravel 5 following [get started guide](http://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter) but result is no matching record. when I check ajax manually, result has one user inside json file.

Route:

```
Route::get('/target' , [
    'as' => 'targets', 'uses' => 'TargetController@show'
]);

Route::controller('datatables', 'TargetController', [
    'anyData'  => 'datatables.data',
    'getIndex' => 'datatables',
]);
```

View:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#targets-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('datatables.data') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
            { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
            { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
            { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at' }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function show()
{
    return view('targets');
}

public function anyData()
{
    return Datatables::of(TUser::query())->make(true);
}
```

Datatable Table with search and pagination is loaded normally and the problem is just about data loading.

Result of checking **datatables/data** page is :

```
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":1,"recordsFiltered":1,"data":[{"id":1,"name":"saaaaaaa","email":"aaaaaa","remember_token":null,"created_at":"2016-02-03 13:00:01","updated_at":"2016-02-03 13:00:01"}],"queries":[{"query":"select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as \"row_count\" from \"users\") count_row_table","bindings":[],"time":1.75},{"query":"select * from \"users\"","bindings":[],"time":0.72}],"input":[]}
```

Comment: can you post what ajax: '{!! route('datatables.data') !!}', is on the created page?`

Comment: I think everything is clear. that line is ajax request to **datatables.data** route, and result of it is last JSON in question.

Comment: "Result of checking datatables/data page is :" Clearly, you state that you are not sure if the ajax request executes, any information from the network tab in the browser?

Comment: Yes, ajax request is ok. I checked it on browser development tool, exactly in firebug.